# C# .Net coding of FileTypesMan

Tags: .net, registry

I'm trying to write my own code to do some of the features in FileTypesMan. FileTypesMan is a free tool that can change file extension description in Windows File Explorer / Manager, as well as the icon. I tried to research how FileTypesMan manages to change the file extension description but in vain.

I successfully changed the description of .html files from the default "HTML Document" to "HyperText Markup Language". Then I did a full search into the Registry to find the word "HyperText", but there is not a single exists.

If the change made by FileTypesMan is not in the Registry, then where the change is made?

Comment: Maybe [Monitoring when registry keys are modified](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cobold/2011/11/29/monitoring-when-registry-keys-are-modified/) helps.

Comment: If there is any change in the registry, in my opinion, it should involve the word "HyperText". But the word does not exist there in any form: Data, Value or Key. I suspect that File Manager reads the extension description else where. But where?

Comment: Did you maybe run FileTypesMan as an Administrator (using UAC) and then searched the registry in your own user context? I'd rather suspect you are looking at 2 different things.

Comment: Different registry for different user? That's new to me. Anyway, the PC/laptop basically belong to me only and I'm with the administrator account. But let me check if there is other administrator account.

Comment: That's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and I suspect you may not find changes under `HKEY_USERS`. If you only ever use one (administrative) account, you should be able to exclude that possibility.